# Como exibir erros no formulário

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos

Estou trabalhando com o padrão de projeto [(PRG) Post Redirect Get](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get)).

Possuo 3 arquivos

> 1 - Classe `Pessoa.PHP`
>
> 2 - `formulario.PHP`
>
> 3 - `processa_form.PHP`

Qual é a melhor forma para tratar e exibir erros de uma aplicação web?

Segue um exemplo

```
class Pessoa {
   private nome;
   private ano_nasc;
   private cpf;

   public function getAno_nasc(){
       $this->ano_nasc;
   }
   public function getNome()....
```

o problema começa com os métodos `set`

Qual é a melhor forma de retornar os erros de `set` e `insert` para a página que contém o `form`?

Pensei nas seguintes possibilidades

> 1 - Achei pouco efetivo pois não saberei ao certo o motivo do erro

```
public function setAno_nasc($ano){
        if ($ano > 3000 || $ano < 1900 )
            return false;
        else
            return true;
```

> 2 - Achei melhor mas ainda acho que futuramente pode dar problema pois
>   vou ter que unir todos os erros de `set` e depois exibir na página do
>   `form`

```
public function setAno_nasc($ano){
        if ($ano > 3000 || $ano < 1900 ){
       return "Ano inválido";
   }
public function setCpf($cpf){
        if (strlen($cpf) > 11)
           return "CPF inválido";    
}
```

> 3 - Dessa forma achei melhor mas não sei se é correto

```
public function setAno_nasc($ano){
        if ($ano > 3000 || $ano < 1900 ){
             $_SESSION['erro'] .= "Ano inválido#";
        }
}

public function setCpf($cpf){
        if (strlen($cpf) > 11)
           $_SESSION['erro'] .= "CPF inválido#";    
}
```

O funcionamento é o seguinte:

> 1- A pessoa acessa o `processa_formulario.php` e envia os dados para o
>   `processa_form.php`
>
> 2- O `processa_form.php` instancia uma pessoa e seta os dados vindos do
>   `formulario.php` nos atributos, verifica se está tudo certo e salva no banco depois
>   redireciona para o `formulario.php` com os erros ou com a mensagem de
>   sucesso.
>
> 3- O `formulario.php` exibe se conseguiu efetuar o cadastro ou não, caso
>   não, ele informa os problemas para que possam ser corrigidos

Me alonguei um pouco para que não haja dúvidas no entendimento do problema.
Esse é um modelo resumido do meu problema, minha classe pessoa possui mais de 50 atributos. (Uso uma função dinâmica para setar todos os atributos da classe)

Comment: Sempre vejo o problema que me parece maior que o que as pessoas em geral notam, o uso desenfreado de OOP para qualquer coisa (não é contra OOP, é contra o mal uso), acham que usar OOP resolve tudo, acham que fica mais organizado, acham que "aumenta a produtividade" ... vou resumir, seus scripts parecem MUITO simples, nem precisaria de OOP para processar o form, seria mais proveitoso preencher uma classe (se realmente fosse necessário) acaso tudo validasse. Mas as pessoas não querem saber, elas só querem usar o que parece mais bonito com diversas desculpas, não é uma critica direta a ti.

Comment: @AloneIn já tentou lançando um throw new Exception?

Comment: vai exibir o erro no mpmento errado ( durante o set ). Preciso que seja exibido a validação do form na página do form

Comment: Então você precisa que seja validado todos os campos para mostrar todos os erros que tiverem ao mesmo tempo?

Comment: Exatamente isso

Comment: Geralmente tratativas de formulários são realizados em duas etapas. A primeira com javascript fazendo validações que não precise se comunicar com a aplicação e o banco. A segunda validação é na aplicação e utiliza-se `throw exception` para exceções no código. O que vc quer fazer parece ser mais uma tratativa de javascript do que na aplicação.

Comment: Se eu tratar tudo em javascript fica muito fácil de burlar as validações